# Can't get P3 spot instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to aws-ec2.

I'd like to make spot request for a `p3.2xlarge` instance in my local region (EU-Ireland) to benchmark V100 Tesla GPUs against my home GPU for deep learning.

I have already requested and have been granted a limit increase for 1 instance of this type in my region.

I fill in the usual spot request application form changing only the instance type to `p3.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 61 GiB EBS only)` and the security group to `SSH` for logging in via my IP.

I can see the instance p3.2xlarge instance type listed among the instance types in the fleet request settings.

`p3.2xlarge  8 vCPUs 61GiB   $0.9915/hr  70 %`

`p3.2xlarge  8 vCPUs 61GiB   $0.9915/hr  70 %`

`r3.4xlarge  16 vCPUs    122GiB  $0.3019/hr  80 %`

`r5d.2xlarge 8 vCPUs 64GiB   $0.1512/hr  76 %`

`r5a.4xlarge 16 vCPUs    128GiB  $0.3023/hr  70 %`

`r3.2xlarge  8 vCPUs 61GiB   $0.159/hr   79 %`

`r4.2xlarge  8 vCPUs 61GiB   $0.1903/hr  68 %`

`i3en.2xlarge    8 vCPUs 64GiB   $0.3/hr 70 %`

`m4.4xlarge  16 vCPUs    64GiB   $0.3056/hr  66 %`

I submit and when the request is fulfilled, I can see the instance type that was assigned is an `r5d.2xlarge` not a `p3.2xlarge`. This instance doesn't even have an Nvidia graphics card and is therefore useless for my comparison.

How do I make a spot request for a `p3.2xlarge` that will be filled by the same instance type as I have requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Spot Fleet* aims to meet your capacity requirements across a range of instances. This reduces the risk of any unavailability of a specific instance type or family affecting your workload.

As you are interested in only one specific machine type, you will need to remove the other types from your spot fleet request; or just create a separate [spot instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html) request for the `p3.2xlarge` (a plain [spot instance request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html), not a spot fleet request)

Comment: Thanks @JamesJJ. I unchecked Apply Recommendation and add my preferred instance type to the list (must match the instance type selected above) and got what I requested.